# How to calculate time between dates error?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

`SELECT OrderID,  ShippedDate, OrderDate,  DATEDIFF(ShippedDate,OrderDate) as AverageLead
FROM order;`

I am getting a 1064 error and I keep trying to troubleshoot this problem I have null values in my response what am I doing wrong. I am trying to get in the end an average of all these days but without this calculation its useless[sample database names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idwkB.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that order is a restricted word .

Use Backticks

```
SELECT OrderID,  ShippedDate, OrderDate,  DATEDIFF( ShippedDate,OrderDate) as AverageLead
FROM `order`;
```

Comment: Thank you I would have been running in circles. My overlooking that error